# Prove by Mathematical Induction $3^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod 4$ for every natural number n.

Tags: proof-writing, induction, modular-arithmetic, congruences, proof-explanation

Prove by Mathematical Induction $3^{2n}\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ for every natural number n.

Comment: What are your tries? Do you know what is $9\bmod 4$?

Comment: why must you use induction?

Comment: Bas case is n = 1 which is congruent.

Comment: Induction is required by my math 429 proof class

Comment: $9^{n}-1^n=8\left(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}+\cdots+9^1+1\right)$

Comment: @user But this does not use induction. But a nice short proof.

Comment: Richard, please do not deface your questions here.

Comment: you would also need to use that $1\cdot 1=1$ (somehow all posted answers ignore this important fact).

Answer (score 3):

Base case : $9\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 4\ )$ is true.

Suppose $9^n\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 4\ )$

Then $9^{n+1}=9\times 9^n\equiv 9\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 4\ )$

Comment: I understand where you are getting this, but i need this to work for any natural number, not just proving 9 congruent to 1 mod 4

Comment: I showed $9^n \equiv1\ (\ mod\ 4\ )$ for all $n$ by induction. And we have $3^{2n}=9^n$

Comment: Yes you have, but I am trying to get 3^2k+2 ≡ 1 (mod 4)

Comment: @Richard $3^{2k+2}=9^{k+1}$.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very bad at this class. I cannot, grasp the concepts of induction proofs.

Comment: The idea of the induction : If a claim is true for $n=1$ and you show that, assuming it is true for some $n$, then it is also true for $n+1$, you can conclude that the claim is true for $n=2$ (because it is true for $n=1$) , then for $n=3$ (because it is true for $n=2$) and so on. In fact, the claim must be true for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ $3^2\equiv 1 \pmod 4$
Now suppose that $$3^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod 4$$ and you have to demonstrate that $3^{2n+2}\equiv 1\pmod 4$ Indeed $3^{2n}\cdot 3^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$

Comment: I need to demonstrate that 3^2(k+1) congruent 1 (mod 4)

Comment: Indeed look my answer...

Comment: Does this work for all natural numbers though?

Comment: Sure..${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: how are you taking 3^2n +2 and making that into 3^2n * 3^2

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have $3^{2(n+1)}=3^{2n}\cdot 3^2$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $3^{2n}\equiv 1\bmod 8$.

Indeed, by the binomial theorem, $3^{2n} = 9^n = (8+1)^n = 8a + 1$.

Comment: Induction is in the binomial theorem...